# C# await tasks + infinite loop still freezing the UI

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

I am trying to get the proper 'structure' for monitoring the state of a game from external source(s) using (Tasks) async/await in order to run the tasks in an infinite loop, however the current way its written seems to just freeze up my UI.

What I have so far:

(in the "state machine" class)

```
// Start monitoring the game state for changes
public void Start()
{
    tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;
    IsRunning = true;
    task = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Run(()=>CheckForStateChange());
            await Task.Delay(1000); // Pause 1 second before checking state again
        }
    }, token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

Without the above "Task.Delay" line the UI completely freezes up.  With the "Task.Delay" line it doesn't freeze up, but if I try to drag the window it skips back to where I began dragging it.

My assumption with the current code is that the 'await Task.Run()' executes and upon completion the 'await Task.Delay()' executes and then on completion returns to the beginning of the while(true) infinite loop. (ie. not running in parallel).

The CheckForStateChange() signature is as follows:

```
private void CheckForStateChange()
{
    // ... A bunch of code to determine and update the current state value of the object
}
```

Nothing special there, simple non-async method.  I have read through lots of examples / questions here on StackOverflow and I used to have CheckForStateChange as returning a Task (with awaitable actions inside the method) and many other iterations of code (with the same results).

Finally I call the Start() method from the main win32 form (button) as follows:

```
private void btnStartSW_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Start the subscription of the event handler
    if(!state.IsRunning)
    {
        state.StateChange += new SummonersWar.StateChangeHandler(OnGameStateChange);
        state.Start();
    }
}
```

I think the above code is the simplest form I have written the code structure in so far, but apparently its still not written 'properly'.  Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:
The publisher side (state machine class):

```
    // ------ Publisher of the event ---
    public delegate void StateChangeHandler(string stateText);
    public event StateChangeHandler StateChange;
    protected void OnStateChange() // TODO pass text?
    {
        if (StateChange != null)
            StateChange(StateText());
    }
```

Where the StateText() method is just a temporary way of retrieving a 'text' representation of the current state (and is really a placeholder at this point until I organize it into a tidier struct)

IsRunning is purely a public bool.

And the handler in the UI thread:

```
private void OnGameStateChange(string stateText)
{
    // Game State Changed (update the status bar)
    labelGameState.Text = "State: " + stateText;
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing anything particularly sinister at the `StateChange` event raise site (although it'd be nice to see the *actual* `OnStateChange` call), but the `OnGameStateChange` handler is a bit of a worry (as you're not supposed to be able to set control property values from a non-UI thread). Did you happen to set `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` to `false` at some point?

Comment: The 'OnGameStateChange' is the consumer of the event within the UI thread, the OnStateChange (and respective delegate/event) is being published by the state machine class.  (as noted in the update provided).  Currently the StateText() being called is just a method containing a switch statement to take the GameState (enum) and returns a string describing the current state.  I intend on moving the GameState from an enum to either a struct or separate class as a cleaner solution, the enum and switch statements were quick way of handling that logic while building the main functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why the UI freezes**

In terms of the main question: you're already calling your `CheckForStateChange` via `Task.Run`, so there is *no way* that your `CheckForStateChange` will freeze the UI unless it includes calls which are marshalled back to the UI thread (i.e. `Control.Invoke` or `SynchronizationContext.Post/Send` used explicitly, or implicitly via a `Task` started on the UI `TaskScheduler`).

The best place to start looking is your `StateChange` handlers (i.e. `StateChangeHandler`). Also have a look at where the `StateChange` event is raised. You'll find thread marshalling code at one of these sites.

**Other issues**

You're passing the `TaskScheduler` pointing to the UI `SynchronizationContext` to the outer task. You're also passing in `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`. In simple terms you're telling the task factory to "start a task on a dedicated thread, and on the current thread". These two are mutually exclusive requirements and you can pretty safely drop them both.

If, as a result of the above, your outer task happens to execute on the UI thread, it won't really trip you up as the inner call is wrapped in `Task.Run`, but this probably isn't the behaviour you expect.

You are storing the result of `Task.Factory.StartNew` inside a `task` field or property. Note, however, that your `Task.Factory.StartNew` call returns a `Task<Task>`, so the saved `Task` instance will transition to completed state almost immediately unless you call `Unwrap` on it and get to the inner task. To avoid this entire mess, just use `Task.Run` to create the outer task (as it has `Unwrap` semantics built in). If you do that, you can ditch the inner `Task.Run` completely, like so:

```
public bool IsRunning
{
    get
    {
        return task.Status == TaskStatus.Running;
    }
}

public void Start()
{
    tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;

    task = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            CheckForStateChange(token);

            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            await Task.Delay(1000); // Pause 1 second before checking state again
        }
    }, token);

    // Uncomment this and step through `CheckForStateChange`.
    // When the execution hangs, you'll know what's causing the
    // postbacks to the UI thread and *may* be able to take it out.
    // task.Wait();
}
```

Since you have a `CancellationToken` you need to be passing it to `CheckForStateChange`, and checking it periodically - otherwise it only gets checked once, when the `Task` is started, and then never again.

Note that I have also provided a different `IsRunning` implementation. Volatile state is hard to get right. If the framework is giving it to you for free, you should use it.

**Final word**

Overall this entire solution feels like a bit of a crutch for something that should be done more reactively - but I can think of scenarios where this sort of design is valid. I'm just not convinced that yours is really one of them.

**EDIT: how to find what's blocking the UI**

I'll get downvoted to oblivion for this, but here goes:

The sure way to find what's causing postbacks to the UI thread is to deadlock with it. There's plenty of threads here on SO telling you how to avoid that, but in your case - we'll cause it on purpose and you'll know exactly what calls you need to avoid when you're polling for changes - although whether or not it will be possible to avoid these calls, remains to be seen.

I've put a `task.Wait` instruction at the end of my code snippet. Provided that you call `Start` on the UI thread, that should cause a deadlock with *something* inside your `CheckForStateChange`, and you will know what it is that you need to work around.

Comment: With note to the CancellationToken, during my cleanup I took them out because I had many tasks within tasks etc, and I just took everything out (including most of the token functionality) temporarily.

Re: Final Word, sometimes I do head the wrong direction with my logic in accomplishing a task :) but in this case, because the actual state is derived from outside sources rather than internal functionality, I am not sure how I would implement it any other way than reactively maybe I am wrong?  I am going to try the above adjustments shortly and accept this well written answer.

Comment: @AaronMurray, if it's external state you're working with then you're right: there's not much choice. That is, indeed, the one valid scenario I was thinking of.

Comment: Problem resolved. I am a bit embarrassed to admit, it wasn't a task/async/await problem after all. What was actually happening was that one method of calculating the current game state was a method that forced the game window to be active (in order to grab a screenshot), so as I was 'dragging' the ui the method was forcing another window active (thus causing my app window it to jump back during a drag, or not be dragable at all in the case of no Task.Delay(). Your answer helped me clean up my code, provided better clarity, and tipped me off on figuring out the actual problem.

Comment: @AaronMurray, glad you got to the bottom of it. Be careful when making UI-bound calls (i.e. activating a window) from a background thread, and good luck with the rest of the game.

Comment: Yes, I am actually working on a better alternative to that problem as well (but well outside of the scope of this question). Again appreciate your help. and +1 for the TaskStatus.Running implementation, much better way to handle it.